# On a manipulation of little-oh in an exercise on finding the convergence of a series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, notation

The exercise asks to study the following series (find where it converges totally, uniformely and pointwise)

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (\tan{(1 / n)} - \sin (1/ n) ) \frac{1}{x^n}$$

the solution I have wrote down in class is:

Notice that $\tan(x) = x + 1/3x^3 + o(x^3) $ and $\sin(x) = x - 1/6 x^3 + o(x^3)$ so $\tan(x) - \sin(x) = 1/2 x^3 + o(x^3)= x^3(1/2 +o(1))$.

Now I can substitute my result in the series (remembering that we had $\sin(1/n)$ and $ \tan(1/n)$) obtaining:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (1/n)^3(1/2 +o(1)) \frac{1}{x^n}$$

at this point I write that a ratio test is performed and we look at the limit given by

$$ \frac{1}{(n+1)^3} (1/2 + o(1)) \frac{1}{x^{n+1}} n^3 (2 +o(1)) x^n $$

My doubt is on the fact that we can keep both $o(1)$ should we not have $\frac{1}{(1/2 + o(1))}$ instead of $(2 +o(1))$ so why is $\frac{1}{(1/2 + o(1))} = (2 +o(1))$?

Comment: I think I figured this out: $\frac{1}{(1/2 + o(1))} - 2 \rightarrow 0$ as x goes to zero and then the claim follows by bringing the $2$ to the other side right? (stupid me)